# Rescale axis on Seaborn JointGrid KDE marginal plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create a seaborn JointGrid object with scatter+contours in the joint_plot and KDEs in the marginals.  This gets me pretty close, but the y-axis marginal doesn't scale appropriately.  What's the best way to manually rescale the marginal axes?  Thanks in advance!

```
f = p.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
g = sns.JointGrid(xdata, ydata, xlim=(0,1), ylim=(0,1))
g.plot_joint(sns.kdeplot, shade=True, cmap="Greys", n_levels=10)
g.plot_joint(p.scatter, color='#e74c3c', s=1.5)
g.plot_marginals(sns.kdeplot, color="black", shade=True)
g.ax_joint.collections[0].set_alpha(0)
g.set_axis_labels(r'$\frac{\chi_{0}^2-\chi_{\mathrm{null},1}^2{\chi_{0}^2}$', r'$\frac{\chi_{0}^2-\chi_{\mathrm{null},4}^2}{\chi_{0}^2}$')
p.gcf().subplots_adjust(bottom=.15)
p.gcf().subplots_adjust(left=.15)
p.savefig('something')
```

This being a new account, I don't have the reputation to post an image - a link to my attempt is here -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipkeS.png

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control this by accessing the y-marginal axes using `g.ax_marg_y`. From there, you can control the axes limits in the usual `matplotlib` way. In this case, you want to adjust the `xlim`:

```
g.ax_marg_y.set_xlim(0,xmax)
```

where `xmax` is the number you need to manually change.

If you need to, you can find the current `xmax` using `get_xlim()`:

```
xmin, xmax = g.ax_marg_y.get_xlim()
```

Then you could just increase `xmax` by some multiple. For example:

```
xmin, xmax = g.ax_marg_y.get_xlim()
g.ax_marg_y.set_xlim(xmin,xmax*2)
```