# Axis labels being aligned with right most figure when using s

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am having issues aligning the text on my sns.jointplot figure. The x and y labels have been appointed to the right most figure instead of the main figure. I can't find a way for them to be attributed to the main figure only.

My code is below;

```
z = sns.jointplot(load[0:9500], priceerror[0:9500], kind='scatter', dropna = True, stat_func=None, 
                  size=7, ratio=3, xlim=(0,60000));
plt.rc("legend", fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Load (MW)')
plt.ylabel('Price Error (£/MWh)')
plt.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=15)
```

Comment: If you use, for instance, `plt.xlabel`, the label will always be set to the last active axes (which in your case seems not to be the one that you want to adjust. When using plain `matplotlib`, one usually avoids this by altering the `axes` directly with `ax.set_xlabel()`. I was quickly looking at the `seaborn` documentation (I'm assuming that this is `seaborn` and found nothing there, but in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36191906/2454357) it seems like there are certain functions to access the separate axes ...

Answer (score 1):

The rc params should be set before the plotting command that would be affected by it, so move `plt.rc("legend", fontsize=15)` to the top.

The jointplot returns a `JointGrid` instance. This has a method `set_axis_labels` to set the labels.

Finally it provides the axes as `ax_joint` (as well as `ax_marg_y` and `ax_marg_x`). Those can be used for further manipulations with the usual matplotlib methods. E.g. `g.ax_joint.tick_params(..)` for modifying the tick parameters.

```
import numpy as np;  np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rc("legend", fontsize=14)

g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
g.set_axis_labels('Load (MW)', u'Price Error (£/MWh)')
# alterntively g.ax_joint.set_ylabel('Price Error (£/MWh)')

g.ax_joint.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=15)

plt.show()
```